# How to delete borders (rules) in a table defined with the cals package?

Tags: tables, rules, cals

I recently discovered the less known cals package for defining tables HTML-style.

Here is all the documentation that I found:

- http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cals (demo & doc)
- http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101parashchenko.pdf (user's manual)

I can create nice tables but following the directions to delete vertical cell borders does not work. Can anybody help?

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\listfiles

%tables in CALS markup
\usepackage{cals}

%calculate with \textwidth etc.
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\lengthw}

\begin{document}    
\setlength{\lengthw}{\textwidth-5cm}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Aantal uitgangen}
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{\lengthw}{5cm}}

\def\cals@cs@width{0pt} %this should delete column borders but is does not!

\thead{
\brow 
\alignL\cell{} \alignC\cell{\vfil Aantal uitgangen}\erow
    }   
\brow
    \alignL\cell{\vfil$aantal\ gebruikers < 50$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil 1 of 2 uitgangen (cfr. 7.1.2)}
\erow
\brow
    \alignL\cell{\vfil$50 \leq aantal\ gebruikers < 500$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil 2}
\erow
\brow
    \alignL\cell{\vfil$500 \leq aantal\ gebruikers < 1000$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil 3}
\erow
\brow
    \alignL\cell{\vfil $1000 \times n \leq aantal\ gebruikers < 1000 \times (n+1)$
    \\met $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil$n+3$}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the macro `\cals@cs@width` has the character `@` in its name, you need to enclose the part where you use it with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. (→ [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/16595))

```
\makeatletter
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt}%
\makeatother
```

If you use this in the preamble (after loading the `cals` package) of your document, you won’t need to repeat it every time.

If you want to decide for every table whether you want vertical rules (I’d advise against it), you are better off using an `@`-less macro that you also define in the preamble of your document.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\calsNoVertRules}{%
    \renewcommand*{\cals@cs@width}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother
```

Now you can simply use `\calsNoVertRules` to switch vertical rules off.

Comment: This indeed did the trick! Many thanks for the very instructive answer. Hoping to see more cals package users here.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{report}
\listfiles

%tables in CALS markup
\usepackage{cals}

%calculate with \textwidth etc.
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\lengthw}

%my suggestion
\makeatletter

\begin{document}    
\setlength{\lengthw}{\textwidth-5cm}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Aantal uitgangen}
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{\lengthw}{5cm}}

%\def\cals@cs@width{0pt} %this should delete column borders but is does not!

\thead{
%my suggestion
%\def\cals@borderT{0.4pt} %borderTop
%\def\cals@borderB{0.4pt} %borderBottom
%\def\cals@borderL{0pt}   %borderLeft
\def\cals@borderR{0pt}    %borderRight
\brow 
\alignL\cell{} \alignC\cell{\vfil Aantal uitgangen}\erow
    }   
\brow
    \alignL\cell{\vfil$aantal\ gebruikers < 50$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil 1 of 2 uitgangen (cfr. 7.1.2)}
\erow
\brow
    \alignL\cell{\vfil$50 \leq aantal\ gebruikers < 500$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil 2}
\erow
\brow
    \alignL\cell{\vfil$500 \leq aantal\ gebruikers < 1000$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil 3}
\erow
\brow
    \alignL\cell{\vfil $1000 \times n \leq aantal\ gebruikers < 1000 \times (n+1)$
    \\met $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil$n+3$}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to improve your answer, you may want to show how your solution works with a complete document. Usually, this makes clear to the reader how to proceed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner :)

Comment: No problems at all :) If you improve your answer, I'll be very happy to upvote it.